# Appending a carriage return to the end of a detail line

Tags: jasper-reports, newline, carriage-return

I am trying to append a carriage return value (***\n***) to the end of a Detail line and am having problems getting it to work correctly.

I placed a value of ***\n*** in the *textField* Expression for the text field being used for this and though it seems to 'work' when the report is run, when the data is sent to another system via a *.csv* file, the value is getting received as ***\n*** and not a carriage return value. I can now see why this is occurring due to the value being placed in the text field's text expression field.

With the above in mind, I came across a post that confirmed what I just described and it said to place it in an expression and my question is if not in the text expression, should it go in the pattern expression? If not there, what is the correct way to get a carriage return value loaded to a Detail line?

Answer (score 1):

Set this on your exporter

```
JRCsvExporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.RECORD_DELIMITER, "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531981/changing-csv-record-delimiter

short answer, use 
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.record.delimiter" value="&#x0D;&#x0A;"/>